# Обновление UITableView при переходе TabBar

Tags: xcode, swift, uitabbar

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть кастомные класс для UITabBarController в котором делается нестандартная кнопка. Туда же поместил метод

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if item.tag == 3 {
        print("RELOAD")
    }
}
```

В данном случае когда тапаешь на кнопку 3 то он вызывается. Но вопрос как можно обновить контроллер на которые переходишь.

пробовал сделать метод в том классе, но оно крашится. Подскажите идеи реализации.

Спасибо!

Comment: Необходимо больше информации как контроллеры отображаются.

Comment: Добавил информации. Контроллер который нужно обновлять имеет обычный ViewController, который имеет TableView c инфой

Comment: Что значит обновить? И код необходимо добавлять кодом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждый раз при отображении контроллера вызывается метод:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогают, уже пробовал